# Regex Validating Lat & long

Tags: regex, latitude-longitude

I am a complete newbie to reg ex and have been tasked with trying to update our regex validators. Currently, they check that the lat and longs are real but now we need to make sure that they are within a certain box. 
Since a user can hand type it in or select it from a map we get them in different styles (minutes/degrees as well as decimal) that we need to account for.

Desired validation--

> LAT 50 through 72 & LONG: -130 through -180 OR 172 through 180)

Current RegEx--

```
LAT:
"^(-?((90((\.0{1,15})|(\:00\:00))?)|(([0-8]?\d)((\.\d{1,15})|((\:[0-5]\d){2}))?)))$"

LONG: "^(-?((180((\.0{1,15})|(\:00\:00))?)|(((\d{1,2})|(1[0-7]\d))((\.\d{1,15})|((\:[0-5]\d){2}))?)))$"
```

I did try to google it and was playing around with this

```
^[+]?([1-8]?\d(\.\d+)?|50(\.0+)?),\s*[+]?(72(\.0+)?|((1[0-7]\d)|([1-9]?\d))(\.\d+)?)$
```

but I am having a problem even reading it so I can't tell how to update it:

> Typical inputs: Latitude could be either 52.5 OR 52:30:00

Comment: This is *not* a very good approach. Just use standard numeric regexes, and then parse the captured strings as numbers and check if they're in the valid range. Using regex for that is unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Can you show us input?

Comment: There may be trouble ahead...

Comment: Lucas, how could you implement a standard numeric regex that would accept both decimal and hour/minute/second values?

Comment: There are also actual lat/long parsing libraries for most major languages - you can just leverage their work to create a LatLong object or something and then call .toInt or whatever, check if it's in acceptable ranges. Agree with @LucasTrzesniewski however you look at it regex is a bad tool for the job (on its own).

Comment: thanks @a-p The problem we are having with using non regex type validators is all questions are added to this form dynamically and there isn't currently a reliable way on the code side of the form to clue in on a lat/long question type to grab the value from, so validation can't be done on the code behind leaving us with the unfortunate option of using regex in undesirable way. I suppose we could also find a way to use a javascript but there are no javascript programmers on our team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If regex had to be used (as [mentioned in your comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33025982/regex-validating-lat-long#comment53877866_33025982)) I would probably go with something like this for "lat" with a range of `50` through `72`:

```
^(?:(?:[56]\d|7[01])(?:\.\d{1,15}|(?::(?:[0-5]\d|\d)){1,2})?|72(?:\.0{1,15}|(?::00){1,2})?)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/fNsnjHw75e1UUdrP)

Note I assume here that your example `52:30:00` means that the two number components after the colon must be in the `0` to `59` range.

I'll leave the "long" input checking up to you... but I would highlight that your attempt has some issues:

```
^[+]?([1-8]?\d(\.\d+)?|50(\.0+)?),\s*[+]?(72(\.0+)?|((1[0-7]\d)|([1-9]?\d))(\.\d+)?)$
```

- it includes the `+` symbol - this was not mentioned in your example inputs
- it includes `,` and white-space `\s*` detection - why is this here - again your example inputs don't allow the user to enter comma or white space.

Focus on writing a regex for one range at a time, `-130 through -180` first then `172 through 180`, then combine the two seperate regular expressions with a `|`.

You also didn't mention which language your regular expression was for - I assumed JavaScript - but you should be careful if this isn't the case - and more clear in future questions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had tried to use a generator to create this one and, not knowing regex didn't know if the [+] was looking for an actual + or was just saying it was a positive number. Same excuse goes for , and \s*. I appreciate your help especially in explaining why my solution didn't work, because now I feel a little more equipped to work on the long validation myself!

Comment: I'll also say that you should think of your input as a sequence of characters, not a positive or negative number.